# How to Pick a Part of String (After = Special Character)

Tags: php

I have a string like this

```
man=teabaran=marcomword=1&rolw=sunglassess
```

or

```
 tina=gdjf==5=?hdhfg=oliver-people
```

and I need to grab only the string after the last `=`. Then the `$result` will be `sunglassess` or `oliver-people`.

Can you please let me know what function in PHP I can use to do this?

Comment: Either [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string, or use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with regex.

Comment: from the manual: `// get last directory in $PATH
$dir = substr(strrchr($PATH, ":"), 1);`

Answer (score 2):

This can be done without exploding, and in 1 line of code, like so:

```
$string = "man=teabaran=marcomword=1&rolw=sunglassess";

$last = substr($string, strrpos($string, '=') + 1);

echo $last;
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is always after the last equation sign (=), then you could simply explode it and take the last part:

```
$str = 'man=teabaran=marcomword=1&rolw=sunglassess';
$arr = explode('=', $str);
$result = $arr[count($arr)-1];
echo "Last element: " . $result; // sunglasses
```

A regex would suit you as well (though it seems a bit like an overkill, unsure what kind of strings/urls you have in the first place):

```
$str = 'man=teabaran=marcomword=1&rolw=sunglassess';
$regex = '/rolw=([^&=]*)/i';
// that this, take every character except &= unlimited times and capture them
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `end` function to advance the array pointer to the last element

```
$str = 'man=teabaran=marcomword=1&rolw=sunglassess';

$array = explode('=',$str);

$last = end($array);

print $last;
/* will output
sunglasses
*/
```

same thing for the second string, all in one go

```
$str = 'tina=gdjf==5=?hdhfg=oliver-people';

$last = end(explode('=',$str));

print $last;
/* will output
oliver-people
*/
```